# Need to specify cyclic alkenes as cis or trans

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm studying organic chemistry from John McMurry's book. Double bond's substituents can be on cis or trans configuration. An example for cyclic molecules is [trans-cyclooctene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-Cyclooctene) and [cis-cyclooctene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cis-Cyclooctene), where the cis compound is more stable. On the other hand, in a naming exercise this molecule is named simple as -cyclohexene. None of the other molecules  in the same exercise was named as cis or trans.

[image]

So, my question is: In small rings is not necessary to specify cis or trans orientation because the trans orientation is less stable (maybe impossible to obtain)?

Comment: Impossible to obtain trans in rings smaller than 8-membered

Comment: IUPAC nomenclature does not use E/Z (cis/trans) for rings smaller than 8-membered.

Comment: Can one of you post as response and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both @Waylander's and my Comment are true as well as your conclusion. From the IUPAC Blue Book 2013:
[image]